# working with json webook php

Tags: php, json, webhooks

I have a problem with receiving webhook data. 
Wobhook data is send in JSON format like this:

```
{
"event_name": "chat_finished",
"chat_id": 5302,
"widget_id": "9IpBqsF7Mt",
"visitor": {
    "name": "v",
    "email": "",
    "phone": "",
    "number": 106597,
    "chats_count": 2
},
"chat": {
    "messages": [
        {
            "timestamp": 1500275477,
            "type": "visitor",
            "message": "<Message text is not displayed here>"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1500275823,
            "type": "visitor",
            "message": "<Message text is not displayed here>"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1500275896,
            "type": "visitor",
            "message": "<Message text is not displayed here>"
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1500276056,
            "type": "visitor",
            "message": "<Message text is not displayed here>"
        }
    ],
    "rate": null
},
"session": {
    "geoip": {
        "region_code": "26",
        "country_code": "UA",
        "country": "Ukraine",
        "region": "Zaporiz'ka Oblast'",
        "city": "Zaporizhzhya",
        "isp": "",
    },
    "utm": null,
    "user_agent": "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/59.0.3071.115 Safari\/537.36"
}
```

}

In my php script I have code like this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
$data = json_decode($data,true);
var_dump($data);
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

In web API log file I see, that my code somehow gets webhook:

Response code: 200, duration: 265msec, Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
<html> <head> <title>CodeIgniter Tutorial</title> <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://crm.t.zp.ua/css/crm-t-zp-ua-1.0.0.css">
```

http://crm.t.zp.ua/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> http://crm.t.zp.ua/js/crm-t-zp-ua-1.0.0.js">

## Home

stdClass Object ( [event_name] => chat_finished [chat_id] => 5302 [widget_id] => 9IpBqsF7Mt [visitor] => stdClass Object ( [name] => v [number] => 106597 [chats_count] => 2 ) [chat] => stdClass Object ( [messages] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 1500275477 [type] => visitor [message] => test ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 1500275823 [type] => visitor [message] => test ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 1500275896 [type] => visitor [message] => test ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 1500276056 [type] => visitor [message] => test ) ) [rate] => ) [agents] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 354276 ) [session] => stdClass Object ( [geoip] => stdClass Object ( [region_code] => 26 [country_code] => UA [country] => Ukraine [region] => Zaporiz'ka Oblast' [city] => Zaporizhzhya ) [utm] => [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 )) *© 2017*

However I do not get any text on the screen and all arrays are empty:

```
NULL array(0) { } array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks in advnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you run the json_decode() twice
try this

```
$contents = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($contents, true);
var_dump($data);
```